# I have multiple checkboxes that filter data, how do I cancel an AJAX call within this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am working on a Project that allows the user to select criteria on the the screen (left hand side) for `Pole` `Country` `City` and there is a table (some widget we are using) that presents the data based on the selected criteria.

Let me paint a picture to give my question some context

**Pole**

- Europe
- Americas
- Asia

**Country**

- United States
- China
- England

**City**

- New York City
- San Francisco
- Beijing

These are just some examples I thought of -- it is more expansive.

Another note, You cannot select `Country` without selecting a `Pole` and you can't select `City` without selecting `Country` (to filter it down even more).

Whenever the user clicks a checkbox next to their selection, a AJAX $.get call is performed with a url that provides data. I believe this URL is actually hitting our Controller class (but this implementation isn't important).

This web application isn't too fast when selecting data, it takes a couple seconds to aggregate the data. Now lets say I have selected
`Americas` and `United States` (each of those makes an ajax call, filtering my data).

If I select `San Francisco` and then decide to select `New York City` instead, it will only give me the data for `San Francisco` and not both of them, the checkbox is checked for both.

Now this makes sense to me since the $.get calls are asynchronous. The first call is winning the race condition.

Nevertheless, this has been reported as a bug and I need a solution on how to solve it. I'm not very proficient in Javascript, and I was wondering if anyone has any ideas.

I was playing around with deferred objects, if I could figure out a way to make it work with those but I couldn't.

It would be nice to maybe terminate ANY ajax call before making this ajax call? This way, the san francisco call will be terminated but the call with both cities would make it through.

Any thoughts anyone?

Thansk!

Comment: $.get returns an xhr object, you should call abort() on that object to terminate the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your ajax to a variable which mostly returns a `XMLHttpRequest` request.

Then you can abort that particular request. You can try in these lines

```
var requestPool = null;

var request = $.ajax({
     ...
     ...
     beforeSend: function() {
         // Check if requestPool is not null
         // abort the previous request
         if(requestPool) {
             requestPool.abort();
         }
         // add the current request to the pool
         requestPool = request; 
     },
     success: function() {
         // your success callback
     },
     complete: function() {
        // no more requests
        requestPool = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks interesting! Can't test it out until Monday morning though, I'll check back with you!

Answer (score 0):

If You are tracking the handles to the $.get calls you can abort them.

Possibly store all relevant ajax calls in an array and loop through and abort them. When 
clicking a checkbox.